# Erro databinding no Android Studio 2.1.2: package databinding does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

Estou tentando aprender databinding e está ocorrendo um erro estranho quando tento fazer o Build:

```
Error:(8, 54) error: package br.com.aulas.vitor.cadastrodecarro.databinding does not exist
```

Meu Build.gradle está assim:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "br.com.aulas.vitor.cadastrodecarro"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Ocorre um erro na linha:

```
import br.com.aulas.vitor.cadastrodecarro.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
```

Já tentei da o Clean e Make Project mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

O erro só ocorre quando tento rodar ou executar o Make Project.

Eu já tinha feito outros projetos para aprender databinding e nunca ocorreu esse erro.

Estou usando Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o que foi.
Foi um erro no arquivo do layout.

Comment: Conforme o @snewtMs comentou, poderia compartilhar a solução?

Answer (score 0):

Fala Morpheus,

Altere essa linha:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Por essa:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'
```

E tenta compilar de novo.

Abraços.

Comment: Alterei mas ao sincronizar o Gradle ocereu o seguinte erro Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.databinding' not found.